# Input is implicitly converted to octal

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

When I get input from a user, if a 0 precedes the input, the value automatically is converted into octal.

```
int c;
cin>>c;
cout<<c;
```

`Input: 0110
 Output: 72`

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's actually a per compiler setting, what compiler are you using? [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/peOwF.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/peOwF.png)

Comment: I am using the one that comes with Turbo C++ 3.1 (Yes, my school insists on using Turbo C++)

Comment: Try `cin>>std::dec>>c;`.

Comment: @TimHinz Well not exactly. An integer assigned to a value with a 0 preceding will be interpreted as an octal

Comment: @songyuanyao I get the error `Type qualifier std must be a struct or class name`. Probably due to the fact that I'm using Turbo C++

Comment: Yeah, `std` is a namespace for standard C++. Turbo is old and doesn't support it, I suggest you update your compiler. With plain C++: http://ideone.com/kZtN4f

Comment: Then `cin >> dec >> c;`? Seems weird. Sorry I'm not familiar with TC...

Comment: @AndrewL. Like I mentioned before, my school insists on using Turbo C++. If there isn't any way to solve this issue on Turbo, please let me know

Comment: @songyuanyao `cin>>dec>>c;` works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::dec`

```
     cin >>std::dec>>c;
```

Comment: Well, without `std::` qualifier, since Turbo C++ doesn't support it.